# 'Trying to help someone, but the other party doesn't appreciate it'

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that best describes trying to help someone, but the other party doesn't appreciate it?

I'm looking for a word.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I think that this can depend on the situation. Some people sometimes don't appreciate that their particular impositions of helpfulness are actually counter-productive. Though I wouldn't downvote – perhaps someone doesn't like OP's grammar ('but' is not linking balanced statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[unrequited](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unrequited?q=unrequited)**

> (of a feeling, especially love) not returned: *Scion shared his wishes to learn more of the world first-hand to Kara unrequitedly.*

Though more commonly used in the context of, and paired with, *love*, the basic definition applies to any feeling or action, or even an object perhaps.

Braden, *Abraham Lincoln, Public Speaker*, [p.94](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Om9vf6x6O8AC&pg=PA94&dq=%22two%20hundred%20and%20fifty%20years%20of%20unrequited%20toil,%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9jLvUqDBE8WNrgeWsIHgAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22two%20hundred%20and%20fifty%20years%20of%20unrequited%20toil,%22&f=false)

> Yet, if God wills that it continue, until all the wealth piled by the bondsman's two hundred and fifty years of **unrequited toil** shall be sunk, and until every drop of blood drawn with the lash, shall be paid by another drawn with the sword, …

Shoup, *Public Finance*, [p.145](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=N_JHg2A2uw0C&pg=PA145&dq=%22unrequited%22%20-love&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MDHvUpi1FMbXrQft7YH4Dg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22unrequited%22%20-love&f=false)

> Types of unrequitted payment: Payments not made for a consideration are **unrequited payments**. When paid by the government to the private sector, they are subsidies or welfare payments.

Answer (score 3):

A thankless task.
Not sure there's a single noun that covers it. The obvious adjective would be unappreciated.

Answer (score -3):

Ungrateful.

Pretty obvious answer.

Comment: Neither an obvious nor a correct answer. The asker is looking for a word for (the actions of) the person _providing_ the unwanted help, not the person who doesn’t want it. ‘Ungrateful’ means almost the exact opposite in this scenario.